# Spring Integration: @ServiceActivator is not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I have the following class:

```
@Configuration
public class SpringIntegrationTest {

    @Bean
    public SimpleWebServiceInboundGateway testInboundGateWay (){
        SimpleWebServiceInboundGateway simpleWebServiceInboundGateway = new SimpleWebServiceInboundGateway();
        simpleWebServiceInboundGateway.setRequestChannelName("testChannel");
        simpleWebServiceInboundGateway.setReplyChannelName("testChannel2");
        return simpleWebServiceInboundGateway;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel testChannel() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel testChannel2() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "testChannel", outputChannel = "testChannel2")
    public DOMSource foo(DOMSource request) {
        System.out.println("asd");
        return request;
    }

    @Bean
    public EndpointMapping soapActionEndpointMapping(SimpleWebServiceInboundGateway testInboundGateWay ) {
        UriEndpointMapping uriEndpointMapping = new UriEndpointMapping();
        uriEndpointMapping.setUsePath(true);
        uriEndpointMapping.setEndpointMap(createEndpointMapping(testInboundGateWay ));
        return uriEndpointMapping;
    }

    private Map<String, Object> createEndpointMapping(SimpleWebServiceInboundGateway testInboundGateWay ) {
        Map<String, Object> endpointMap = new HashMap<>();
        endpointMap.put("/ws/test", testInboundGateWay );
        return endpointMap;
    }

}
```

Even tough the service activator is subscribed for the "testChannel", I get the followin message:

> o.s.i.w.SimpleWebServiceInboundGateway - failure occurred in gateway sendAndReceive: Dispatcher has no subscribers for channel 'org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext:/MyProject restful API.testChannel'.; nested exception is org.springframework.integration.MessageDispatchingException: Dispatcher has no subscribers

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add `@EnableIntegration` to one of your configuration classes.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a dispatcher to the  testChannel  would fix this issue.