# Spring Integration 2.2.3.RELEASE @ServiceActivator not invoked

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, integration, spring-annotations

I have a legacy code with these versions (Spring version: 3.2.1.RELEASE and Spring Integration version 2.2.3.RELEASE). I would like to migrate all xml configurations of spring integration to java configuration. 
Before starting the migration, I am making some test and I am struggling with `@ServiceActivator` which does not work. 
My example is:

```
@Configuration
@ImportResource("classpath*:integration-config.xml")
public static class IntegrationConfig {
    @Bean
    public MessageChannel queueChannel() {
        return new QueueChannel(5);
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel pubSubChannel() {
        PublishSubscribeChannel publishSubscribeChannel = new PublishSubscribeChannel();
        publishSubscribeChannel.subscribe(new MessageHandler() {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message<?> message) throws MessagingException {
                System.out.println("First handler :" + message.getPayload());
            }
        });

        publishSubscribeChannel.subscribe(new MessageHandler() {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message<?> message) throws MessagingException {
                System.out.println("Second handler :" + message.getPayload());
            }
        });
     return publishSubscribeChannel;
    }
}
```

And :

```
@MessageEndpoint
public static class MessageEndpointDefintion {

    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "queueChannel")
    public void queueActivator(String payload) {
        System.out.println("Payload from queue : " + payload);
    }

    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "pubSubChannel")
    public void pubSubActivator(Message<String> message) {
        System.out.println("Payload from pub-sub :" + message.getPayload());
    }
}
```

When I send some messages in the channels any `@ServiceActivator` is invoked.

As indicated [here:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38397999/6643803) , adding `@EnableIntegration` (available since version 4 of Spring Integration) could solve the problem, but in my case I am using the version 2.2.3 which does not provide this annotation. If they provide this annotation in this version, I think we can use it but how?

Other question, can I upgrade Spring Integration version to 4 with the same version of Spring (3.2.1)?
Thanks

**EDIT**

I call my configuration like this: 
     `AbstractApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(IntegrationConfig.class);` and an example of test:

```
PublishSubscribeChannel publishSubscribeChannel;
publishSubscribeChannel = (PublishSubscribeChannel) context.getBean("pubSubChannel", MessageChannel.class);
publishSubscribeChannel.send(MessageBuilder.withPayload("==PUB-SUB-CHANNEL== ").build());
```

And `integration-config.xml` :

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.springframework.org/schema/c"
   xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd">

<int:annotation-config/>

<xsd:element name="annotation-config">
    <xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:documentation>
            Enables annotation support for Message Endpoints.
        </xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>
</xsd:element>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing missing to add into your XML config this:

```
<int:annotation-config/>

<xsd:element name="annotation-config">
    <xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:documentation>
            Enables annotation support for Message Endpoints.
        </xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>
```

Unfortunately that old version can't go just with plain annotations. The whole Spring Integration engine is triggered from XML.

And no: you can't upgrade Spring Integration without upgrading Spring Framework.

Comment: In my main class I use annotation config :`AbstractApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(IntegrationConfig.class);`

Comment: Well, you don't listen: Spring Integration is still not going to work there with just plain Java & annotation configuration. You need to add at least simple XML with that tag and `@ImportResource` it on your `@Configuration`

Comment: I added one and import it as suggested but same result. I edited my post for more infos

Comment: Works fine now, it seems like using `@ServiceActivator` for a queue channel causes some trouble since we have any way to define a poller inside the annotation. Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Right, you can't use `QueueChannel` for `@ServiceActivator` in that old version. That becomes available in face of `@Poller` sub-annotation since version `4.0`

Comment: What about the `@Gateway` annotation usage in this old version? In the doc (https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-integration/2.2.3.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#gateway) It's not specified how to enable it. When declaring it in xml file, it works fine but not with the annotation. The bean is not found.

Comment: Right, you still have to declare it in the xml.